The isomorphism $K_0(X) \cong \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z \oplus \text{Pic}^0(X)$ for a smooth projective variety
Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve and $K_0(X)$ the Grothendieck group of coherent sheaves over $X$. I read that there is an isomorphism $$K_0(X) \cong \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z \oplus \text{Pic}^0(X),$$ but I have some lack in understanding $\text{Pic}^0(X)$. If $[F] \in K_0(X)$, then we can consider $$(\deg(E), \text{rank}(E)) \in \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$$
but what is this $\text{Pic}^0(X)$ and why does it appear here? Apparently this is called the connected component of the identity in the Picard group, but I have no idea why it should appear here. Why don't I just have $$K_0(X) \cong \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z?$$

There is a canonical map
$$
K_0(X) \to \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathrm{Pic}(X),
\qquad
[F] \mapsto (\mathrm{rank}(F), \det(F)),
$$
and this map is an isomorphism. On the other hand, there is a canonical exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathrm{Pic}^0(X) \to \mathrm{Pic}(X) \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0,
$$
where the second map is given by the degree, and it is split (non-canonically) by a choice of a degree 1 line bundle on $X$. Using a splitting you can get your non-canonical direct sum decomposition.

Thank you. I forgot to consider the determinant.
